# Please synonymise the tags on prostration

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The following three tags are the same:
[prostration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prostration) , [sujud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sujud) , [sajda](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sajda)